# Is this conversion from SQL to LINQ correct?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Below is the simple SQL query

```sql
select RelationshipID from Relationships r
where
r.RequestReceiverID = 3 and
r.RequestSenderID = (select MemberID from Members m
                     where m.Name = 'Cipla')
```

The above query works fine and gives me the expected results.

I am currently trying to learn LINQ

So, I tried to convert the above SQL Query to LINQ

Here is my attempt

```
var relation = 
    (from relationship in db.RelationShips
     where relationship.RequestReceiverID == LoggedInUserID && 
           relationship.RequestSenderID == 
               (from m in db.Members
                where m.Name == SelectedUserName
                select m.MemberID).FirstOrDefault()
            select relationship).FirstOrDefault();
```

But when executing the above query I get the following error

```
Invalid column name 'Member_MemberID'.
Invalid column name 'Member_MemberID1'.
```

**EDIT**

Next I am trying to update the data in the database

```
relation.StatusID = (from p in db.StatusMasters
                     where p.Status == Status
                     select p.StatusID).FirstOrDefault();

db.SaveChanges();
```

**Edited as per the request from AgentFire**

```
//Members.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Munim_File_Sharing.Models
{
    public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public DateTime MemberSince { get; set; }
        public int MemberTypeID { get; set; }

        public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
        public List<Relationship> RelationshipSender { get; set; }
        public List<Relationship> RelationshipReceiver { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like something is wrong between the mapping of database columns to object properties

Comment: I have created models myself. I mean I don't have the auto-generated models.

Comment: then in there you somewhere access columns named Member_MemberID1 andMember_MemberID?

Comment: I believe you need to let the Linq engine to auto-create models for you. That will cover auto-update detection for you as well.

Comment: Show us that model `Member` you created yourself, please.

Comment: @AgentFire I have edited my question as per your request

Comment: @olydis I dont have any word in my whole solution named Member_MemberID1 and Member_MemberID. Also I dont have MemberID1.

Comment: As a general advice when learning LINQ. Download and enjoy www.linqpad.net plus a local instance of the northwind database. I strongly advise buying premium. You can fire up linq and sql queries alike and compare you're results, without going through debugging in vs and looking for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get member ID

```
var memberId = (from m in db.Members
                where m.Name == SelectedUserName
                select m.MemberID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Get Relation

```
var relation = 
    (from r in db.RelationShips
     where r.RequestReceiverID == LoggedInUserID && 
           r.RequestSenderID == memberId
     select r.RelationshipID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Your query, did you try...

```
var relationID = 
    (from relationship in db.RelationShips
     where relationship.RequestReceiverID == LoggedInUserID && 
           relationship.RequestSenderID == 
               (from m in db.Members
                where m.Name == SelectedUserName
                select m.MemberID).FirstOrDefault()
            select relationship.RelationshipID).FirstOrDefault();//added RelationshipID to the query
```

based on the EDIT of the question...

Get member ID

```
var memberId = (from m in db.Members
                where m.Name == SelectedUserName
                select m.MemberID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Get Relation

```
var relation = 
    (from r in db.RelationShips
     where r.RequestReceiverID == LoggedInUserID && 
           r.RequestSenderID == memberId
     select r).FirstOrDefault();
```

update the status..

```
if (relation != null){
  relation.StatusID = (from p in db.StatusMasters
                     where p.Status == Status
                     select p.StatusID).FirstOrDefault();

db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. But still I dont understand what the problem is in my query?

Comment: @Khushi, I have put the select back in.  You changed it to `select r` which will give you all the fields, which is not what you want?

Comment: Yes, I need all the fields. I am getting error while retrieving all the fields. But I dont get any error when I try to retrieve only RelationshipID. For more details see the updated question. Please see the code below the word Edit in bold in my question.

Comment: The question has completely changed in the edit section...your `SQL` will only retrieve one field `select RelationshipID from Relationships`, are you now saying you actually need `select * from Relationships`?  Now it looks like you're trying to get a relationship record, and update the status?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am trying to update the status and for that I need all the fields of Relationships.

Comment: Before checking for nulls like if (relation != null) I have the above query which returns me an error

Comment: Use my two queries in that case, since I don't have VS to test your query.

Comment: I have removed RelationshipID from the query...you should not get a relation object.

Comment: For more details on my models please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853792/can-anybody-point-me-to-right-direction-on-creating-models-manually-in-mvc

Comment: @Khushi, you're unlikely to get help if you change question content, and then jump to a new question before the last one was resolved.  You started with a simple question of **Is this conversion from SQL to LINQ correct?** and then the content changed to help with an update.

Comment: I think you are mis-understanding me. I think your queries are absolutely fine but my models may be generating some issues. So I asked the another question on manually creating models.

Answer (score 0):

> You Cannot write a query like that I think u need something like that

```
var relationID = (from relationship in db.RelationShips
where relationship.RequestReceiverID == LoggedInUserID &&
db.Members.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name==SelectedUserName).MemberID == relationship.RequestSenderID
select relationship 
).FirstOrDefault().RelationshipID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one more Helpful**

```
var MemberList=from m in db.Members.where(x=>x.m.Name ==    SelectedUserName).select(x=>x.MemberID)).toList();

var relationID = (from relationship in db.RelationShips.where(x=>x.RequestReceiverID == LoggedInUserID && MemberList.contains(x.RequestSenderID))
                   select relationship).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That will split one good query into two consequetive. Which will cost double on performance.

Comment: Also, your `.toList()` is quite wrong, because it should return either null or the only member, so its `SingleOrDefault`, which should throw an exception if for some reason there are TWO members with the same username,